# Добавление модели со связанными данными с одной страницы

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Имеются две модели со связью один-ко-многим

Модель Bid

```
public class Bid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

Модель Document

```
public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int? BidId { get; set; }
        public virtual Bid Bid { get; set; }
    }
```

Мне необходимо реализовать страницу с добавлением заявки (Bid), на которой возможно добавить сразу документы, например, при помощи modal bootstrap (всплывающего окна).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне реализовать контроллер, который мог бы добавлять документы, к еще не добавленной заявке.

P.S. Смогу реализовать эту штуку с использованием jQuery, который генерирует разметку, и связывателя модели, но такой подход плохо сопровождаемый и сложно тестируемый. Должен быть другой способ :)

Что делаю я:
Создаю EditorTemplates для Bid и Document

Bid

```
@model Intrasite.Domain.Entities.Bid
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Documents)
```

Document

```
@model Intrasite.Domain.Entities.Document
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

Делаю View на создание заявки:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
{
@Html.EditorForModel()    

a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Добавить документ /a

div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Documents)  
...
/div
input type="submit" value="Создать заявку" /
}
```

И дальше начинаются проблемы. Я не могу добавлять отдельно, через отдельные методы, документы к заявке, так как она еще не добавлена. У меня есть контроллер с методом

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var bid = new Bid()
            {
                Documents = new List() {new Document()}
            };
            return View(bid);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Bid bid)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(bid);

            repository.CreateBid(bid);

            return View(bid);
        }
```

Так как я передаю заявку с созданным документом `Documents = new List() {new Document()}`, то соответственно я могу заполнить только один документ.
Также я создавал метод

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDocument(Bid bid)
{
     bid.Documents.Add(new Document());
     return View("Create", bid);
}
```

Который позволил мне добавлять множество документов, но все криво.

Хочу узнать, как всё же реализуют умные люди, такие связи

Comment: Укажите в каком именно моменте возникает сложность. Например: "Вот примерно когда заявка уже есть и всё добавить получается, а вот заявка  только создаётся и поэтому не получается. Можно сделать вот так, но так мне не нравится." Т.к. сейчас не очевидна суть проблемы, а также не видно предпринятых усилий и вопрос выгляд как "напишите мне нужный код".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае вы не должны физически создавать заявку до тех пор, пока в неё не добавлены нужные документы. Всплывающее окно, которое используется для добавления документа не должно отправлять запрос на присоединение документа в базе данных.

Вместо этого вы должны посылать его методу, который по этому вопросу построит кусок формы (HTML `form`), и вернёт его через AJAX на основную страницу.

В деталях этот процесс выглядит так:

1. На основной форме, которая самая обычная форма, у вас есть кнопка добавления документа. При нажатии на эту кнопку появляется всплывающее окно с формой для добавления документа. Насколько я вижу, там будет просто текстовое поле, куда можно ввести URL. Появление всплывающего окна реализовано средствами JavaScript.
2. Отправку второй формы (во всплывающем окне) надо перехватить. Вместо отправки обычного запроса надо послать AJAX-запрос одной из акций вашего контроллера:

Посмотрим на код акции:

```
public ActionResult AjaxCreateDocument(string url)
{
    return PartialView("CreateDocumentView", url);
}
```

**CreateDocumentView.cshtml**

```
@model string
@Html.Hidden("documents", Model)
```

3. В результате AJAX-запрос будет возвращать кусок HTML-кода вида `<input type="hidden" name="documents" value="введённый пользователем URL" />`. Вам надо добавить его к основной форме, например, средствами jQuery.
4. И только когда основная форма будет заполнена, её можно отсылать на сохранение.

Схема будет работать за счёт правильного имени hidden-поля, т.е. `documents`. Когда биндер ASP.NET MVC встречает поля с одинаковым именем, он может привязать всех их к коллекции. В вашем объекте как раз есть такое поле `ICollection<Document>`.

Для большей управляемости я бы посоветовал в явном виде разделить модели разных уровней. У вас одни и те же классы используются и для отображения данных, и для сохранения их в базе, и для обработки их на уровне бизнес-логики. Из-за этого, в частности, вам управлять не очень нужными Вам полями `Id`, `BidId` и т.д.

Второе — если будут сложности с биндингом, посмотрите [этот (классический) пост](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/). Он поможет, если простое имя `documents` не сработает.

Comment: Спасибо, вам, огромное за совет! Сейчас попробуй реализовать эту идею. Только, всё же, получается такие связи делаются за счет jquery, за счет генерации html формы и, в последствии, передачи в контроллер за счет биндера моделей. Скажем, если в проекте будет очень много таких связей, то на это достаточно много времени уходить будет.

Comment: Всё то же самое можно сделать без AJAX, просто выглядеть будет "как в старом вебе". Тут важно, что данные не отправляются сразу в базу, а сначала крутятся некоторое время между клиентом и сервером. И конечно, пока они крутятся, со стороны сервера они приходят как сгенерированная HTML-форма, а со стороны клиента как заполненные поля в этой форме.